# aws-cdk RFDK_X509Generator creation fails with openssl: command not found

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openssl

I get the following error

```
7:15:02 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | Custom::RFDK_X509Generator                  | RenderQueueRootCA4708D079
Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Command failed: openssl req -x509 -passout env:CERT_PASSPHRASE -newkey
rsa:2048 -days 1095 -extensions v3_ca -keyout /tmp/tmp.metU8N/key -out /tmp/tmp.metU8N/crt -subj /CN=RenderQueueRootCA/O=AWS/OU=Thinkbox
/bin/sh: openssl: command not found

Error: Command failed: openssl req -x509 -passout env:CERT_PASSPHRASE -newkey rsa:2048 -days 1095 -extensions v3_ca -keyout /tmp/tmp.metU8N/key -
out /tmp/tmp.metU8N/crt -subj /CN=RenderQueueRootCA/O=AWS/OU=Thinkbox
/bin/sh: openssl: command not found

at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:402:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:458:11)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:301:12) (RequestId: 7a1fa905-f9e4-4643-9db6-9d250c8ec59c)
```

when running `cdk deploy` on the following rfdk code

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { aws_s3 as s3, 
  aws_lambda as lambda, 
  aws_apigateway as apigateway, 
  aws_ecr_assets as ecr_assets, 
  aws_ecr as ecr,
  aws_ec2 as ec2,
  aws_efs as efs } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as ecrdeploy from 'cdk-ecr-deployment';
import {deadline as deadline} from 'aws-rfdk';
import * as rdfk from 'aws-rfdk';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';

function build_thinkbox(scope: Construct){
  const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(scope, 'Vpc', { maxAzs: 2 });
  const version = new deadline.VersionQuery(scope, 'Version', {
    version: '10.2.0',
  });
  let imgs = new deadline.ThinkboxDockerImages(scope,'Thinkbox Images', {
    version:version,
    userAwsCustomerAgreementAndIpLicenseAcceptance: deadline.AwsCustomerAgreementAndIpLicenseAcceptance.USER_ACCEPTS_AWS_CUSTOMER_AGREEMENT_AND_IP_LICENSE
  });
  const repo = new deadline.Repository(scope, 'Repository', {
    vpc:vpc,
    version:version,
    // Allow resources to be deleted when we delete the sample
    removalPolicy: {
      database: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      filesystem: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
    },
  });
  const renderQueue = new deadline.RenderQueue(scope, 'RenderQueue', {
    vpc:vpc,
    version:version,
    images:imgs.forRenderQueue(),
    repository:repo,
    // Allow the load-balancer to be deleted when we delete the sample
    deletionProtection: false,
  });
}

export class AppStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    build_thinkbox(this);
  }
}
```

with the following dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.70.0",
    "aws-rfdk": "1.2.0",
    "cdk-ecr-deployment": "^2.5.30",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
```

I don't understand why I get such error as I definitely have openssl installed

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

I'm not sure if this is my fault or perhaps a bug in the library itself, hence I also created this issue with precise steps for reproduction in a docker environment
https://github.com/aws/aws-rfdk/issues/1108

In case this is something on my end that could be easily fixed I'm also posting this issue on stackoverflow (and then close the issue on github).